# What is words in uint256?

Tags: solidity

Let's take two variable:

```
uint256 public smalldata = 50000;     
uint256 public data = 500 * (10**6) * 10**18;
```

The first on prints:

```
BN {
  negative: 0,
  words: [ 50000, <1 empty item> ],
  length: 1,
  red: null
}
```

But second one prints this:

```
BN {
  negative: 0,
  words: [ 0, 34604957, 24241406, 1654, <1 empty item> ],
  length: 4,
  red: null
}
```

What do the "words" mean? How it's calculated?

When I use data.toNumber() it gives following error:

```
Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits
```

But smalldata.toNumber() gives 50000.

How to print the correct value of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I use `data.toNumber()` it gives `Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits`

That's because in Javascript, the value of `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is `2 ** 53 - 1`.

I mean, it would be, if `2 ** 53` was a safe integer (if you know what I mean)...

Anyway, as a general rule, avoid converting `BN` objects to `Number`.

In order to print `data`, you can simply use `data.toString()`.

More generally, for any action that you want to apply on a `BN` object (for example, comparing it with another `BN` object), use the set of functions provided by the `BN` library, which you can find [here](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/#utilities).

Note that decimals are not supported in this library, so in order to apply a decimal operation on a `BN` object, you first need to convert it to a string, then to either a [`BigNumber`](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/) object or a [`Decimal`](http://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/) object, and then apply the decimal operation provided by the library that you have chosen to use.